# How can I automatically rotate my screen at start up?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, eee-pc

I want to set my screen to portrait mode automatically when I'm startting Windows. Can I make some code to do this or should I use iRotate?

Answer (score 0):

This is normally a setting in the video drivers. Try downloading the latest video drivers from the manufacturer of your video card (not from the manufacturer of your laptop) and you may find that you have a lot more options and settings available.